# Octave: 3D Surface plot for Gaussian distribution

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, octave

I am very new to Octave and Matlab,

I am trying to plot a surface plot for Gaussian distribution to visualize anomaly detection using two features (x axis and y axis) of a data set and the Gaussian value (z axis).

```
   X1           X2       Z(the Gaussian value )  

0.00000       3.0000          0.0153130  
2.00000       2.8000          0.0457589
2.20000       3.0000          0.0550785
2.30000       2.0000          0.0163526
2.40000       2.2000          0.0252592
2.70000       3.5000          0.0615501
2.70000       4.2000          0.0259381
2.90000       3.0000          0.0695891
4.10000       1.6000          0.0088349
4.40000       3.5000          0.0812291
4.40000       4.5000          0.0179289
4.80000       3.2000          0.0886546
5.90000       3.0000          0.0734376
6.30000       3.0000          0.0658523
5.90000       4.0000          0.0407246
6.40000       4.0000          0.0353848
6.20000       3.0000          0.0678455
6.30000       3.6000          0.0576709
8.20000       3.8000          0.0195292
10.00000      2.7000          0.0054764
```

Below given is a plot similar to which I desire:

[image]

My Attempt:

I tried creating a mesh-grid for each dimension and did a surfplot on the matrix, but It didnt work. It gave me a weird plot, Which is shown below

```
[X1,Y1]=meshgrid(x1',x2');
[Z]=meshgrid(z');
surf (X,Y,Z)
```

[image]

I'd be glad If somebody help me get the graph correctly

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to interpolate between the given 2D co-ordinates to try and create a Gaussian surface.  What you need to use is `griddata` [(Octave doc)](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Interpolation-on-Scattered-Data.html) [(MATLAB doc)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/griddata.html), where you specify your `(x,y,z)` points, then specify the 2D co-ordinates that form the output surface that you want.  To do this, you can use a combination of `meshgrid` [(Octave doc)](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/meshgrid.html) [(MATLAB doc)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) and `linspace` [(Octave doc)](http://octave.sourceforge.net/octave/function/linspace.html) [(MATLAB doc)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) to help you generate those points.

We can use `linspace` to generate a linear set of points for each axis from the minimum to the maximum of each axis.  By default `linspace` will generate 100 points between a given minimum and maximum, so let's stick with those.  After, use `meshgrid` to generate the final grid of 2D points you want your Gaussian surface to occupy.  You then use `griddata` using the input `(x,y,z)` points as well as the final grid of 2D points generated from `meshgrid` to generate your final surface.  Because of the "curviness" of the Gaussian curve, I would specify the `cubic` flag to perform bicubic interpolation in the regions outside of your control points that define your Gaussian curve.  `griddata` by default uses bilinear interpolation, but let's override and use bicubic instead.

Without further ado, assuming `X1`, `X2` and `Z` are all vectors loaded in your workspace, this is the code to interpolate and generate the surface:

```
limitsX = linspace(min(X1), max(X1));
limitsY = linspace(min(X2), max(X2));
[X1out,X2out] = meshgrid(limitsX, limitsY);
Zout = griddata(X1, X2, Z, X1out, X2out, 'cubic');
surf(X1out, X2out, Zout);
title('Interpolated Gaussian Surface');
xlabel('X1');
ylabel('X2');
zlabel('Z');
```

This is the surface I get:

[image]

This doesn't resemble the actual Gaussian curve (... more like a botched raised tent), and the reason why is because the data you have sampled from your Gaussian distribution is too sparse and the control points are far away from each other.  For the points that are in between the control points, you have to interpolate and the interpolation won't be as accurate as the actual points coming from the Gaussian distribution itself.

If you're serious about building a Gaussian surface, you should actually generate the points from the mathematical definition of the Gaussian, then the surface plot will certainly look accurate.

Comment: Hi rayryeng- Just for curiosity since griddata interpolates the 2D coordinates, When I use interp2 which i presume does similar stuff : Zout = interp2(X1, X2, Z, X1out, X2out); the code gives me error "error: interp2: X and Y size must match the dimensions of Z". Could you please tell me where i am going wrong

Comment: @user2404193 - Yeah, you can't use `interp2` because it assumes that the input is **gridded** data.  I use `griddata` because you can specify only a vector of inputs and `griddata` interpolates in between those co-ordinates.  My guess is that they use some sort of scattered method, like delaunay triangulation to find those values.